# Excel - Text Or Number Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm wondering if there's a shortcut to the following.

I have a product form that customers will fill out and I need the formula to format the part numbers they enter correctly. If it doesn't their entry doesn't match the products list.

Below are the variety of text/number/other variations...
[Excel Columns/ Rows Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWZqC.png)

```
    101
7-2009
7-5601-RT
G-2121
5728B
PI-PIXES
```

I got all but the last one working with this formula: 
**FORMULA1**

```
=AND(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(--MID(B40,ROW($1:$9996),1)))<LEN(B40),MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},B40&"0123456789"))<=LEN(B40))
```

I also have to keep it in .xls format. 
Basically, I have one column that checks this above and it returns TRUE/FALSE.

I have another formula that checks for text:
**FORMULA2:**

```
=IF(I40=FALSE,"NUMBER", "TEXT")
```

The final column TESTS FOR TEXT/NUMBER.
**FORMULA3:**

```
=IF(J40 = "NUMBER", VALUE(B40), B40)
```

PI-PIXES is flagged as number because of the dash(hyphen).

Without any other option, I'm considering adding a third column to find TEXT with hyphens. I would then change FORMULA3 check if both if column 1 = TRUE+column 2 = TRUE and column 3 = TEXT but this is getting complicated and I'm wondering if there's a shortcut.

Comment: so would `7-2009` be text or number?

Comment: What's the expected format, and what are some examples of the incorrect format? You might want a UDF if it's too complicated.

Comment: 101 needs to be a number and the rest should be text.

Comment: 7-2009 should be text

Comment: I ended up adding another column to check for Other (-) and then a fourth column to set whether it's text or number. It now correctly sorts all of these examples into text or number but that PI-PIXES doesn't match to part number. Frustrating!

Comment: Added link to file.

Comment: I would like to see a definition of "format the part numbers they enter correctly". Your formula is very complex and doesn't seem to deliver much more than `IFERROR(VALUE(B40),B40)` would do. That, from my observation, doesn't format the part number correctly. In your example, I entered 5728 B, and got 5728 B in response, not 5728B which is the correctly formatted version of the part number. Can you be a little more clear what you're trying to do?

Comment: Start the last line with an apostophe - which will make it text again

Comment: 5728B matches the part on the other page while 5728 B doesn't.
I'll have to test out the IFERROR ; I vaguely remember trying that.

Comment: Basically, if it's a number, it gets formatted as value() and if not it's left alone. The problem is that each one of these part number presents three different characteristics and I had to test for each of those because some appear to be numbers but aren't.

Comment: I tried IFERROR(VALUE(B40),B40)
it fails because it converts the 7-2009 to a date...thanks Microsoft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does it:

```
=IF(SUBSTITUTE(B40,"-","")<>TEXT(B40,"@"),B40,IFERROR(VALUE(B40),B40))
```

If there are hyphens, it returns the B40 unchanged, eliminating dates. Otherwise, it handles it as a normal Value conversion with IFERROR.

This should work for older versions of Excel:

```
=IF(SUBSTITUTE(B40,"-","")<>TEXT(B40,"@"),B40,IF(ISERR(VALUE(B40)),B40,VALUE(B40)))
```

Or even this:

```
=IF(ISERR(FIND("-",B40)),IF(ISERR(VALUE(B40)),B40,VALUE(B40)),B40)
```

Comment: Actually, it looks like the `SUBSTITUTE` function is not available for .XLS versions of Excel. So, this may not work for you. Humble apologies.

Comment: Thanks for trying Stone; your example appears to replace the hyphen with a "" blank space, is that what it's doing?

Comment: This moves things forward; I wonder if there is a replacement for SUBSTITUTE...I think that's what is failing compatibility. It certainly simplifies things.

Comment: This moves things forward; I wonder if there is a replacement for SUBSTITUTE...I think that's what is failing compatibility. It certainly simplifies things. Also, it still fails the PI-PIXES part number and doesn't match. There may be something else going on with that...

Comment: That ended up working for PI-PIXES; I had a named data set that I had not expanded to include new products I added. So, it wasn't available...

Comment: please explain what SUBSTITUTE is doing. It appears to substitute a hyphen for blank and what is the @ character used for?

Comment: Yes, `SUBSTITUTE(B40,"-","")` is temporarily removing hyphens. `TEXT(B40,"@")` is converting to a text value. So, "7-2018" becomes a comparison of "72018" to "7-2018". Since they are different, you have hyphens. When there are hyphens, the `IF` statement returns B40 with no changes. Otherwise, it does the comparison I suggested in the comments to your OP. This method first eliminates dates, then allows the `IFERROR` to work as planned.

Comment: So, it turns out that the compatibility problem wass not the `SUBSTITUTE` command, but the `IFERROR`. After a little research and testing, I was able to put together a clean formula that works for you. I have updated the answer. You should be able to accept that answer.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't seeing your solution...Both of those worked...quite creative. Thanks so much for helping...